# Sabre: Modify an air segment

Tags: soap, sabre

I'm trying to modify an air segment in a reservation of Sabre. From my knowledge, I assume that the steps to do it will be:

1. Search for changeable air segments
2. Calculate fee to modify segment(s) A to segment(s) B
3. Add new segments B to reservation
4. Remove old segment(s) A
5. Pay modification fee
6. Commit changes
7. Verify that the air segments in reservation is changed successfully

According to [this Sabre document](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/management/itinerary/Update_Itinerary/examples?nid=9214) looks like I can only perform step 3 and 4. For other steps I cannot find any relevent documents. Can anyone help me how to do the other steps ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps I've implemented.

1. retrieve booking
2. eTicketCouponLLSRQ to validate coupon status
3. StructurFareRules  to validate the fare has Cat31 fare rule
4. GetTicketProfie to determine fee collection method for carrier (or store locally)
5. ExchangeShopping to return valid options with fare differences and fees
6. ota_cancel to cancel unwanted segments
7. enhancedAirBook to sell new flight segments (from Exchangeshopping selection)
8. AutomatedExchanges (compare step) to price the exchange
9. AutoamtedExchanges (commit step) to create the PQR
   10 EndTransaction to finalize changes.

(steps 6-10 can be replaced with ExchangeBookingAPI)

Then normal fulfullment using AirTicketRQ